# Reverse Engineering a delphi 2010 code - UML tool

Tags: delphi, uml, delphi-2010

I am looking for a software that can reverse engineering a delphi 2010 project and create a class diagram.
I've tried some software out (ModelMaker, Enterprise Architect) but they don't work as I expect.
Enterprise Architect is not able to reverse engineering a Delphi 2010 code, it does not understand, for instance, generics in the code. http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?num=1292432202.
ModelMaker is too complex, I really don't like the way it was built (the interface is terrible IMHO).
So you guys have suggestions about a good UML tool that works with Delphi 2010? It does not matter if it is free or paid. I just want a good UML tool.

Comment: I have no problem with ModelMaker doing such a thing. Can you specify your problems with MM a little bit?

Comment: I just did. I dont like the interface, the lack of space to draw diagrams and so on. ModelMaker is not a option to me, sorry.

Comment: My space to draw diagrams in MM spreads over (nearly) both of my monitors if I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness sake:

You can do round trip-engineering with **Rational Rose**. You just need to download an extra piece of software: http://cc.codegear.com/partners/delphi7disk2/ensemble_systems/rose_delphi_link/index.html

It's old though, and probably doesn't support the new language features. I've played with it a couple of years ago, and then decided this whole round-trip engineering is just too distracting.

...

At some point we all come to the same conclusion: UML's usefulness is highly overrated.

Especially when doing round-trip stuff, your level of detail is mostly the problem. Either there's too much information, making diagrams unreadable, or they become more high-level, and then you miss out on crucial details.

Comment: +1 for the point about UML. I use UML for 2 things: sketching a rough picture of how the analysis works out, and for reverse engineering an existing piece of code to get a rough idea on how it was designed.

Comment: OK .. thanks for the advice. I will stop trying to use UML for reverse engineering and I will use it only for sketching.

Answer (score 1):

The Delphi built-in class diagrams can be used for reverse engineering your code.

Comment: And the Delphi built-in class diagrams does not auto create relashionship when I reverse engineer a project.

Comment: Then I think you have already tried the best available UML alternatives. But I'm anxious to see if others have seen different tools.

Comment: I also found Agilian (http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/ag/) but i think it is only for java users. Its a shame.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a project called [StarUML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/staruml/files/staruml/5.0/) that was a Delphi add-in that was far more advanced than the built in UML support. Unfortunately (for Delphi users anyway) the project changed directions and started a complete redesign written in Java. The original Delphi source is available as a download but hasn't been worked on since 2006 so it won't include support for generics, anonymous methods, helper classes, etc.

Other than the choices you've already mentioned this was the only other round-trip engineering project for Delphi that I'm aware of.

Comment: Yes. I've tried it and it really sucks. I guess I'll have to stay with modelmaker or EA for now.

Comment: After downloading this program (I downloaded the old Delphi version) I only see tools menu I only see options to reverse engineer Java, C++, and C#. I don't see anything for delphi. Do you know how this works?

Answer (score 0):

WhiteStarUML (old name was StarUML)
https://sourceforge.net/projects/whitestaruml/
But it has issues on High DPI.

But better to use built in UML methods: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTpAAz3WkZk